# How many unique words starting with a can be obtained from given m a's and n b's?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am stuck at this questions while trying to understand permutations. How would I get number of unique words and how can I know they all start with a.

I am not able to understand how we proceed in this question, still I did something like this:

I fixed one 'a' from m a's in the starting of the word. I have now m-1 a's and n b's.

Now how do we get the number of words and also ensure that they are unique.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Start with two simpler problems first. How many words are there made up of one  $a$ and two  $b$'s? You can write them all down. Then think about how each is determined by its length, the number of $b$'s and where they are. (The problem is easier if you are required to use all the letters each time - your post doesn't make that clear). You're right to note that then you can just prefix each word with an $a$ to get the answer you need.

Comment: Do you mean all the words of length at least $1$ or all the words of length $m + n$?

Answer (score 0):

Use stars and bars:  you have $m$ places to put $n$ $b$'s.

So, ${n+m-1\choose n}$.

I'm using [theorem two](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @bof if $m=1$ we just get the one word starting with $a$. Yes, I assumed words of length $m+n$.